# How to get all the properties of the table are connected Many-to-Many (error:java.lang.String cannot be cast)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three database tables is: Role, User, UserAndRole. I wanted to create a site administrator can manage user accounts, it can display all the attributes of the user and roleName. I do not know how to be displayed when the User class List  Role class and have List . I think my way is not good so anyone can give me ideas?

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "musicstore")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "fristName")
    private String fristName;
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Order> lOrder;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "userandrole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleId") })
    private List<Role> lRole;
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", catalog = "musicstore")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "roleId")
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name = "roleName")
    private String roleName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "lRole")
    private List<User> lUser;
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;
    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        session.getCurrentSession().save(user);

    }

    @Override
    public void editUser(User user) {
        session.getCurrentSession().update(user);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int userId) {
        session.getCurrentSession().delete(findUser(userId));

    }

    @Override
    public User findUser(int userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (User) session.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, userId);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByName(String username) {
        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", username));        
        return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<User> ls= session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
        Iterator<User> iter = ls.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            User user = iter.next();
            Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select r.roleName from user u, userandrole n, role r where u.userId=n.userId and r.roleId = n.roleId and u.userId =:userId");
            query.setParameter("userId", user.getUserId());
            List<Role> lr=query.list();
            for(int i =0; i<lr.size();i++){
                user.getlRole().add(lr.get(i));
            }
        }
        return ls;
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User()); 
        return "home";
    }
    @RequestMapping({ "admin/hr" })
    public String setupForm1(Map<String, Object> map) {
        User user = new User();
        map.put("user", user);
        map.put("userList", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "hr";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/hr.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result,
            @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map) {
        User userResult = new User();
        switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
        case "add":
            userService.addUser(user);
            userResult = user;
            break;
        case "edit":
            userService.editUser(user);
            userResult = user;
            break;
        case "delete":
            userService.deleteUser(user.getUserId());
            userResult = new User();
            break;
        case "search":
            User searchedUser = userService.findUser(user.getUserId());
            userResult = searchedUser != null ? searchedUser : new User();
            break;
        }
        map.put("user", userResult);
        map.put("userList", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "hr";
    }
}
```

hr.jsp

```
<table border="1">
                    <th><spring:message code="user.userId" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.fristName" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.lastName" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.address" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.password" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.userName" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.phone" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.email" /></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="user.status" /></th>
                    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${user.userId}</td>
                            <td>${user.fristName}</td>
                            <td>${user.lastName}</td>
                            <td>${user.address}</td>
                            <td>${user.password}</td>
                            <td>${user.userName}</td>
                            <td>${user.phone}</td>
                            <td>${user.email}</td>
                            <td>${user.status}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
```

Comment: can u post the exception stack trace here to identify the problem

Comment: just want to make sure that `UserStatus` is an enum right?

Comment: yes, it's an enum. I deleted Role class and add a variable to Class User is admin, admin variable is added to the user table in the database. I have solved the problem of decentralization, but I still do not think that's the model database suitable for the decentralization.